# Is there any way to build a source of go, including struct type, to a *.so file?

Tags: python, go, hybrid

I'm constructing an application written by python.

In the application,
I need a function provided by a go language, so I'm trying making a *.so file to use it as a local library.

How should I build the *.so with a go-lang source containing struct-type.

---

Go version : go version go1.12.2 windows/amd64

python : Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]  on win32

---

Up to now, I succeeded to build a *.so file with a go-lang source, just having a simple function without any struct type. And it worked by executing it via python-code.

Then, I added a struct parameters on the go-code, after that, tried a same build process. However, it never did work, showing some messages like this.

> # command-line-arguments
>
> .\user_auth.go:37:16: Go type not supported in export: http.ResponseWriter
>
> .\user_auth.go:37:40: Go type not supported in export: http.Request
>
> .\user_auth.go:37:16: Go type not supported in export: http.ResponseWriter
>
> .\user_auth.go:37:40: Go type not supported in export: http.Request

According to [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18412), cmd/cgo seems not to support this conversion till 2017.
I could found no more infomation than above.

・Succeeded(ok.go)

```
package main

import (
    "C"
)


func main() {
}

//export adder
func adder(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

・Failed(wish_ok.go)

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "C"

        "google.golang.org/appengine"
        "google.golang.org/appengine/user"
)

func main() {
//  http.HandleFunc("/auth", welcome)
//
//  appengine.Main()
}

func init() {
//    log.Println("Loaded!!")
}

//export welcome
func welcome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
        u := user.Current(ctx)
        if u == nil {
                url, _ := user.LoginURL(ctx, "/")
                fmt.Fprintf(w, `<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>`, url)
                return
        }
        url, _ := user.LogoutURL(ctx, "/")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)`, u, url)
}
```

I expect that go-lang code as above can be executed by python.
Or, some other way to get user information in gcp(gae-py3.X) is welcome.

Comment: currently go plugins (.so) files are only supported on linux,you also need to export the functions / type that you want to use somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the function that you export from Go to C must contain only C types (or primitive Go types that can be automatically converted to C types, like `int`). The documentation explicitly states that [Go struct types are not supported; use a C struct type](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go). (This is also [discussed](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18412#issuecomment-268847417) in the issue you linked.)

So that's why you can't use `http.ResponseWriter` or `*http.Request` in the signature of your exported function. You'll have to either define your own C types to represent an HTTP request and response (probably painful), or break up your local library differently (e.g. define separate `loginURL` and `logoutURL` functions that take and return strings).